# clean up wordpress custom navigation

Tags: wordpress

i have made a custom menu named "header-menu" and i call it in my header.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
'container' => '',
'theme_location' => 'header-menu'
) ); ?>
```

with

```
'container' => '',
```

i want to remove the menu wrapper, but the output still has this:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li> ... </li>
<li> ... </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

but i want to get rid of the annoying

```
<div class="menu">
```

. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're actually doing here but if you want the container to go away you use:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => false,
) ); ?>
```

Review [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for more detail.

Comment: i used "'container' => false," and "'container' => '', ... both not working.

Comment: when i use "'theme_location'  => '',", without pointing to a custom menu, it works ... but i need it to work with a custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

got it working now:

```
<?php $defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => 'footer-menu',
'container'       => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="dl-menu">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 2
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```